# Marpit automated pagebreaks possible with css?

Tags: markdown-it, marp, marpit

Using Marpit makes a lot of fun and I used it every day for creating slides with markdown.

Sometimes I also need a document with several pages and I want to use the environment of marpit there too. The only problem I have: I need to put pagebreaks by hand, which is a lot of work, with trying a preview, moving the break, and so on.

I tried to archive it by css via page directive

```css
@page {
     /* A4 document size */
    size: 210mm 297mm;
    margin: 20px;
}

section {
    break-after: page;
}
```

that did not work out. Is it a lack of css knowledge and am I missing something, or is it not working, because marpit is not supposed to pagebreak automatically?

- Then I started to dig into marpit-plugin system, which is quite cool, but much code to read. Is that the right place to approach automatic paging with marp?
- Can somebody give me a slight push where to start my plugin journey?
- Or do I need to go a level higher and grep the pdf converter?

I saw [md-to-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md-to-pdf), which works nicely, but does not quite fit my already established marp environment, where I use some plugins and self created themes already, which I don't want to miss.